# PDF content stream operators are in reverse order. By using PDFBOX how we can re order it?

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

There are some PDF's which are generated by ocrmypdf library in hocr mode.

```
ocrmypdf.ocr("input.pdf", "output.pdf",pdf_renderer='hocr', keep_temporary_files=True)
```

These all pdf's content stream is in reverse order. The page last line is located first in content stream as shown in below figure.
[PDF file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V42PFMwQsCwzEZoeNOkx3JT5bE3S0r5G/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Because of this when I tag this pdf the jaws is reading last line first in every paragraph tag.

Comment: Changing the order is feasible. But which *is* the correct order? If you happen to have multi-column text, you cannot simply sort top-to-bottom, left-to-right...

Comment: when ever there are three column or two column pdf's we have to   focus on the top to bottom no need to worry on left to right. The first line text content stream we should encounter first in content stream.

Comment: Ok. As said above, that is feasible. BUT if there is not only text, the situation gets complicated. E.g. consider a content stream where first some text is written at the bottom (1), then a page filling rectangle is drawn (2), then some text is written at the top (3), i.e. the text (1) is hidden and text (3) is visible. You now want (3) before (1), but wherever you move (2) then - (3) (1) (2) or (3) (2) (1) or (2) (3) (1), you'll never get both the text (1) hidden and the text (3) visible.

Comment: After I research, I understand that I should shuffle the contents of those streams. How can I do it using PDFBox or IText?