# Order PDF content in content panel based on tagging order ( I want to alter content stream text order)?

Tags: pdf, itext, accessibility, pdfbox, pdf-reader

As we know in pdf the content order is random. Can place text anywhere within the page. This leads to the pdf content order is random not like human reading order.

Because of this when pdf is reading by using some (Orbit Note, Read & Write) screen readers it will read based on the content panel order not tagging order (logical order).

But when you tag content in adobe it's sort the content panel order based on your tagging order or logical order (like Mcid order). Same I wanted to do in my case.

For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64338713/pdf-content-stream-operators-are-in-reverse-order-by-using-pdfbox-how-we-can-re) I know exactly which order I want to arrange the text. I have BBOX(Rectangle) of each and every Tj and graphics state is available.  Is it possible by using Itext or PDFBox can I alter the content order and save the pdf?

In case directly if I can't do? May I override any files in these (Itext or PDFBox) library's will help to achieve this functionality?

The code I tried , But didn't worked.

```
@Component
public class Contentorder {
@Autowired
public static List<Object> sortContentByMCID(List<Object> tokens)         
{
    int min = 2147483647;// max integer value
    int max = 0;
    Map<Integer, ArrayList> indexes = new HashMap<>();
//        ArrayList<ArrayList> indexes = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
    ArrayList indices = new ArrayList();
    for (int ind=0; ind < tokens.size(); ind++) {
        if (tokens.get(ind) instanceof Operator) {
            Operator op = (Operator) tokens.get(ind);
            if(op.getName().equals("EMC") && indices.size() == 2){
                indices.add(ind+1);
                int key = (int) indices.get(0);
                indexes.put(key, indices);
            }
        }else if (tokens.get(ind) instanceof COSDictionary) {
            if( ((COSDictionary)tokens.get(ind)).containsKey("MCID")
                    &&  tokens.get(ind+1) instanceof Operator
                    && ((Operator) tokens.get(ind+1)).getName().equals("BDC")
                    && !((COSName) tokens.get(ind-1)).getName().equals("Figure") ) {
                if(min > ((COSInteger)((COSDictionary)tokens.get(ind)).getItem("MCID")).intValue())
                    min = ((COSInteger)((COSDictionary)tokens.get(ind)).getItem("MCID")).intValue();
                if(max < ((COSInteger)((COSDictionary)tokens.get(ind)).getItem("MCID")).intValue())
                    max = ((COSInteger)((COSDictionary)tokens.get(ind)).getItem("MCID")).intValue();
                indices = new ArrayList();
                indices.add(((COSInteger)((COSDictionary)tokens.get(ind)).getItem("MCID")).intValue());
                indices.add(getLastTf(tokens, ind));
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("print mcid min, max");
    System.out.println(indexes);
    for (Integer key : indexes.keySet()) {
        ArrayList lst = indexes.get(key);
        for (int ind=0; ind < tokens.size(); ind++) {
            if (tokens.get(ind) instanceof COSDictionary) {
                if( ((COSDictionary)tokens.get(ind)).containsKey("MCID")
                        &&  tokens.get(ind+1) instanceof Operator
                        && ((Operator) tokens.get(ind+1)).getName().equals("BDC")
                        && !((COSName) tokens.get(ind-1)).getName().equals("Figure") ) {
                    //some code
                    if(((COSInteger)((COSDictionary)tokens.get(ind)).getItem("MCID")).intValue() < key){
                        continue;
                    }else if(((COSInteger)((COSDictionary)tokens.get(ind)).getItem("MCID")).intValue() == key){
                        break;
                    }else{
                        List<Object> toks = tokens.subList((Integer) lst.get(1), (Integer) lst.get(2));
                        Integer size = toks.size();
                        Integer index = getLastTf(tokens, ind);
                        if(index < (Integer) lst.get(1)) {
                            tokens.addAll(index, toks);
                            tokens.subList((Integer) lst.get(1)+size, (Integer) lst.get(2)+size).clear();
                        }else{
                            tokens.addAll(index, toks);
                            tokens.subList((Integer) lst.get(1), (Integer) lst.get(2)).clear();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return tokens;
}

private static int getLastTf(List<Object> tokens, int ind) {
    for(int i = ind; i > 0; i--){
        if(tokens.get(i) instanceof Operator){
            if( ((Operator) tokens.get(i)).getName().equals("Tf")){
                return i-2;
            }
        }
    }
    return ind;
}
```

}

Comment: Is there a way after tagging pdf is there a way to sort content panel based on Mcid order?

Comment: After I research, I understand that I should shuffle the contents of those streams. How can I do it using PDFBox or IText?

Comment: @mkl please help me here?

Comment: @tilman-hausherr I tried using pdf box can you tell me how to move containers ?

Comment: it's not supported. This would be a whole new subproject.

Comment: As already mentioned in a comment elsewhere, simply shuffling the contents around can change the appearance of a document considerably: content formerly hidden may become visible, content formerly visible may become hidden, arbitrary graphics state variables may be initialized incorrectly, ... Thus, changing the order of the elements of a content stream requires much more finesse than a mere shuffle.